# Create a new page with custom content type but a normal page is created

Tags: content-type, pages

Sorry I am new to custom page content type and not sure what I have missed.

I created a custom content type `XPages` by inherit of `Pages` content type. The only difference is I added a new column `PageType` (a choices field). I didn't created a custom page layout because I only need a new metadata field `PageType`. User can use the default page layout.

Then I bind the `XPages` with the Pages library (I have activated publishing infrastructure). Users click into Pages library can click `New File` -> `XPages` to create a new page. However, the new file created, by default, have a content type `Pages`. Users have to change the content type to `XPages` manually. After change to `XPages` users see the new field "PageType" show up.

Why users create a new page with custom content type `XPages` but a normal page was created?

Comment: You need to modify the pages library to enable management of content types, then modify the order of content types and select XPages as primary (you can even hide the other one). This will default to new content type.

Answer (score 1):

You need an associated PageLayout. The moment you create a page and selects a page layout the associated content type will change.

On the other hand if you upload a page then it automatically picks the default content type `XPages`.

Comment: If you want to take advantage of the columns inside the page, you would need a page layout that understands XPages content type.

Comment: I created a page layout by copying existing page layout files. But how can I bind this layout with my XPages? Also the Design Manager not working because XPages is under subsite...